# Pageblock table not displaying anything after apex function

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, pageblocktable

I have a pageblock table that uses a custom controller to access a custom object through the SOQL. The page, when I click preview, does not load anything from the custom objects. (I've set the SOQL) to retrieve all of the custom objects. I am unable to figure out why there is nothing being loaded on the page. Attached is the code below for the VF page and the APEX controller.

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false"  sidebar="false"    
Controller="ProductByVan">
...
<h1>Cart Details</h1> 


<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!outSku}" var="VAN" style="table">
<apex:column >
 <apex:facet name="header">VAN Type</apex:facet>
 <apex:outputText value="{!VAN.VANType__c}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column >
 <apex:facet name="header">Item Code</apex:facet>
 <apex:outputText value="{!VAN.Item_Code__c}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column >
 <apex:facet name="header">Item Description</apex:facet>
 <apex:outputText value="{!VAN.ItemDescription__c}"/>
</apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>

<style>
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

th, td {
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
</style>
```

Below is the APEX Controller

```
public class ProductByVan{

// The action function parameter gets set here - this is the input
//public String skey {get; set;}

// The output is set here so it can be re-rendered into the page
public List<VAN__c> outSku {get; set;}

 public PageReference retrieve() {
   // TODO why is this only returning on and anarbitrary one at that?
   // Pass in the skey via a bind variable
   List<VAN__c> skus = [
           select Item_Code__c, VANType__c, ItemDescription__c
           from VAN__c
           ];
   // Pass out the value
   outSku = skus;
   return null;
     }
   }
```

Comment: did you put debug statement and try to investigate what goes wrong?

Comment: Is there a specific statement for debugging? When I used the firefox debugger it gives me a JSON.parse() error even though I am not touching JSON....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to dynamically query and display records, you have to do several things:

1. Call a Visualforce action that submits the form data to the server controller.
2. Perform a query on the server and store the results.
3. Perform a re-render in the page to show the information.

Unless you've removed some critical lines of code, you seem to have only coded (2), and I don't see any indication that you're actually calling the action `retrieve()`.

You'd need to have a structure something like this in your page:

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable id="myid" value="{!outSku}" var="VAN" style="table">
            <!-- content -->
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        <apex:commandButton action="{! retrieve }" rerender="myid" value="search" />
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

It's critical to include the command component that calls the action with the `rerender` attribute, to tell Visualforce which elements of your page need to be refreshed after the action returns `null`.